# JavaFX : Logarithmic scale on the X axis

Tags: javafx, scale, axis, logarithm

I followed [this excellent post](http://blog.dooapp.com/2013/06/logarithmic-scale-strikes-back-in.html) to draw charts using a logarithmic scale on Y axis. But, I do need more : I also need a logarithmic scale on the X axis. I tried to modify a bit the source code offered by the site but, I wasn't succesfull.

Here is the result I get with the native code :

[image]

Instead of that result, I'm expecting a "bell". Does someone could give me some tips to adapt this code to an X axis ?

Thank you for your help,

Dr_Click

Comment: What did you try to modify, and what didn't work? From a quick glance at the code it seems to handle both vertical and horizontal axes, so I would have expected it to work for the X axis without modification...

Comment: As I didn't get the drawing expected (I added an image of what I get in my main question), I am looking for what is wrong.